# Wrap div outside foreach loop and echo elsewhere

Tags: php, html, foreach, echo

I want to print a div with a list of errors inside it. The errors are found by iterating inside a foreach loop. I would like this entire div and list inside a variable so that I can print it in the required part.

Here's what I am doing:

```
errmessage = "";
//more code, if etc

else {
    $errmessage .= '<div class="form-error alert alert-danger"><strong>Form submission failed!</strong><ul>';
    foreach($vresult->getErrors() as $v) {
        $errmessage .= '<li>'.$v.'</li>';
   }
   $errmessage .= '</ul></div>';
   }
```

In another part of the file:

```
<form method="post">
<?php
    echo $errmessage;
?>
```

Is this the right way to do it, I want to echo if there are error otherwise print nothing if there aren't any. This works for me but wondered if there were any other good practices.

Comment: You could just set a flag in your first bit, and then have the possible outputs in the second? I'm not sure I totally understand the problem.

Comment: @AbuNooh You posted an else branch without `if`. Please, post the `if` too.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is okay to use, but I suggest using an object oriented approach like this:

```
<?php
class ErrorManager
{
    private $errors = Array();

    public function AddError($errorMessage)
    {
        array_push($this->errors,$errorMessage);
    }

    public function GetErrorMessage()
    {
        $finalMessage = "";

        foreach ($this->errors as &$error) {
            $finalMessage .= $error ."\r\n";
        }

        return $finalMessage;
    }
}
```

-- Usage of the class -----

```
$errMngr = new ErrorManager();

$errMngr->AddError('A failure occured!');
$errMngr->AddError('another failure :(');

echo $errMngr->GetErrorMessage();

//OR Use this for HTML
echo nl2br($errMngr->GetErrorMessage());
?>
```

This way you can get a plain text string using a \n\r delimiter. You can output the errors in your log file and also display them as HTML with `nl2br()`

You can also alter the class to use a div + list like this:

```
public function GetErrorMessageHTMLList()
{
    $finalMessage = "<div><ul>";

    foreach ($this->errors as &$error) {
        $finalMessage .= '<li>'.$error .'</li>';
    }

    return $finalMessage.'</ul></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution looks fine one suggestion is

In else case if you do not want to display "Form submission failed!" message when no errors

```
if(!empty($vresult->getErrors()) {
//Build error message inside
}
```